# How to pass row.entity inside celleditablecondition in UI-grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ui-grid

I am trying to set `cellEditableCondition` based on content of other cell in same row.

For that how do I pass row.entity to cellEditableCondition?

I tried passing row as arguement to function defined oncellEditableCondition but that row object does not have entity property.

I want something like below:

```
columnDefs: [{
  name: 'column1',
  field: 'name',
  cellEditableCondition: function(row) {
    return row.entity.lastname === 'Adams'
  }

}, {
  name: 'column2',
  field: 'lastname'
}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This small tweak to your code should do it:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [{
      name: 'column1',
      field: 'name',
      cellEditableCondition: function(scope) {
        return scope.row.entity.lastname === 'Adams'
      }
    }, {
      name: 'column2',
      field: 'lastname'
    }],
    data: [{name: "Tim", lastname: "Harker"},
           {name: "Akash", lastname: "Adams"}]
  }
}]);
```

```css
div[ui-grid] {
  height: 130px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.0.2/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.0.2/ui-grid.min.css" />
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if you have any other questions.  Happy to help further, if needed.